# How to reveal specific relationship using tSNE?

Tags: clustering, references, tsne

I’ve been using tSNE in attempts of finding and visualising some relationships in my data. I came to a following problem. If my data is say 1000 points, and I want to know about some relations between 10 particular points (I want to know how close are they to each other and other points of my data), tSNE won’t give much attention to them, as 10 is much smaller than 1000.

My idea is to sample a uniform ball with radius R of say 20 points around each of 10 target points, and hence attract tSNE attention to that enlarged thing. If we can find R such that after tSNE we will see a cluster, consisting 10 target points, sampled points and not to many other points from a dataset, we can assume that target points in initial dataset were close.

Do you know, has anybody elaborated on such topic for similar problems, and where can I read about it.

Comment: If you want to compare distances between points, why not simply calculate the distances and  compare them? What benefit would t-SNE add? t-SNE is primarily a visualization tool, and will gladly distort distances in order to squash high dimensional structure down into a low dimension space

Comment: @user20160 I'm sorry, probably I didn't make myself clear in my question. I am talking more about local structure than distances themselves. I.e. I'm interested more in how close target points are relatively to each other and all dataset, than the precise distance between them. I use the density increase exactly for tSNE to preserve structure of points close to target ones. And hope tSNE will give me some visualisation of that